# easy way to change the uniq -c output?

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, sed, uniq

I have a simple file like this:

> Term1 column2 column3
>   Term2 column2 column3
>  
>   Term3 column2 column3
>   Term2 column2 column3
>   Term1 column2 column3
>   Term2 column2 column3

If I sort on the first column and get a count for the terms:

```
cut -f1 -d ' ' file | sort | uniq -c
```

The results shows me this:

> 2 Term1
>       3 Term2
>       1 Term3

But I would rather see this:

> Term1 2
>   Term2 3
>   Term3 1

Is there an easy way to "change" the uniq output to do this or would i still need to pipe the output to sed or awk to get this?

This seems a simple question so my apologies if this was asked before.

Comment: Please use code tags for Input samples rather than quote tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uniq doesn't give the option to rearrange output.

You can do this using `awk` :

```
cut -f1 -d ' ' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'

Term1 2
Term2 3
Term3 1
```

Or using `awk` and then sort  (recommended)

```
$awk '{a[$1]++} END{for (i in a) print i,a[i] }' file | sort -k1
Term1 2
Term2 3
Term3 1
```

Comment: awk one-liner won't guarantee the sorted output. `(i in a)`

Comment: `-k1` is redundant.

Comment: @karakfa: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: `sort -k1` is the default behavior of `sort`, no need to explicitly specify.  Unless you meant `-k1,1`

Comment: @karakfa: Oh okay.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest one with GNU **datamash** tool:

```
datamash -Ws -g1 count 1 <file
```

The output:

```
Term1   2
Term2   3
Term3   1
```